# docker: can I use linux i386 image in an ARM native system?

Tags: docker

I have a library compatible with i386. I want to use this library in my ARM-based system (aarch64). Can I use a docker image of a i386 linux in my aarch64 system?

Comment: You would need an emulator which wouldn’t be fast. So theoretically yes, practically no.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be summed up as "Can I run a i386 container in a ARM host system?"

Yes - you can.

ARM and Docker recently announced a partnership for multi architecture containers. The new Docker Desktop platform makes it even easy to develop cross architecture development.

Here is a great article on the topic: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-images/

The technology behind this, however, is emulating one paltform on another - which maybe comparably slow against the single architecture delivery. However, even it is slow, this introduces portability which was not there before.

Comment: No, it can’t. 32bit x86 is very different from 64bit ARM.

Comment: You are correct. I think I summed up the question wrong. Edited now.